# Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 2525, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() on live website

Tags: php, email

I am getting above error when i click on submit button for send email.

While searching for the solution i find i have to edit the file called php.ini but phpinfo() shows following things

Configuration File (php.ini) Path =>    C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File =>    C:\PHP5\php.ini

and I am not see any folder called windows or php5 in my ftp.
What should be the reason for mail failure error?and how can i find the php.ini file?

Comment: @Dagon i got a ftp from a person & i have to upload the work i done...i don't know much about hosting ...by the way i am not understand your question

Comment: @Dagon ???are you there?